# setReadOnly causes error when called on instanceReady of CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, gwt, backbone.js, ckeditor

I'm trying to set my CKEditor instance to be "readOnly" after the instance has fully loaded but I'm getting a Javascript error: `Cannot call method 'setReadOnly' of null`. When I dig into it, the error is coming from this line in the ckeditor.js, within the `editor.setReadOnly` method: `this.editable().setReadOnly(a);` That means that the editor exists, but the `editable` method/attribute (on the CKEditor instance) does not.

Below is my code, and I'll explain it a little. My app is a combination of GWT and Backbone. The CKEditor itself is created by the Backbone code but the parent element is in GWT so that's where I initiate the `setEnabled` action.

```
private native void setEnabledOnLoad(boolean enabled, String id) /*-{
  CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function(evt) {
    if(evt.editor.name === id) {
      Namespace.trigger(Namespace.Events.SET_ENABLED, enabled);
    }
  });
}-*/;

setEnabled: function(enabled) {
  this.editor.setReadOnly(!enabled);
  if(enabled){
    this.editor.focusManager.focus();
  } else {
    this.editor.focusManager.blur();
  }
}
```

The Backbone class has a listener for `Namespace.Events.SET_ENABLED` that triggers `setEnabled`.

Is there another CKEditor event that I should listen for? There doesn't appear to be an `instanceReady` event on `editable`. What am I missing?

**EDIT**
`this.editor` is created in the Backbone class `render` function like this:

```
this.editor = CKEDITOR.replace(this.$(this.id)[0], config);
```

The reason I don't add the `instanceReady` listener right after it's created is because the function `setEnabledOnLoad` is called in GWT before the instance has been fully initialized. This is a result of having the code in two places. GWT has said "ok, create the instance" but Backbone hasn't finished by the time GWT goes to the next line of code and wants to set it enabled/disabled.

Answer (score 9):

Two years later, but here is my solution. Maybe someone else will find it useful.
As stated above, the event is appearantly triggered before the editable() function is fully set up, and therefore one solution is to simply wait for it to finish before setting it to readonly. This may be an ugly way to do it, but it works.

```
        //Delayed execution - ckeditor must be properly initialized before setting readonly
        var retryCount = 0;
        var delayedSetReadOnly = function () {
            if (CKEDITOR.instances['bodyEditor'].editable() == undefined && retryCount++ < 10) {
                setTimeout(delayedSetReadOnly, retryCount * 100); //Wait a while longer each iteration
            } else {
                CKEDITOR.instances['bodyEditor'].setReadOnly();
            }
        };
        setTimeout(delayedSetReadOnly, 50);
```

Comment: Can't believe you have to do this, but the above code does work.

Answer (score 5):

You could try subscribing to `instanceReady` event this way:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor.on("instanceReady", onInstanceReadyHandler)
```

However, the `editor` instance must have been already created by then (inspect `CKEDITOR.instances` in the debugger).

I'm a bit confused about the difference between `editable` and `editor`. Could you show the fragments of your code where `this.editor` and `this.editable` get assigned?

**[EDITED]** I guess I see what's going on. `CKEDITOR` is a global object, you may think of it as of a class which holds all CKEDITOR instances. Trying to handle events with `CKEDITOR.on` isn't right, you need to do it on a specific instance (like I've shown above). I assume, *"editor"* is the ID of your parent element you want to attach a `CKEDITOR` instance to (please correct me if I'm wrong). I'm not familiar with Backbone, but usually it's done with [replace](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replace):

```
var editorInstance = CKEDITOR.replace("editor", { on: { 
    instanceReady: function(ev) { alert("editor is ready!"); }}});
```

Here we attach a new instance of CKEDITOR to the `editor` parent element and subscribe to the `instanceReady` event at the same time. The returned object `editorInstance` should provide all the [APIs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor) you may need, including [setReadOnly](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setReadOnly). You could also access it through the global `CKEDITOR` object using the parent element ID, i.e. `CKEDITOR.instances.editor`. On the other hand, [editable](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable) is rather a service object available on [editor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor). I can't think of any specific case where you might need to use it directly.

Comment: `CKEDITOR` does hold all instances, but it also does a lot more. The reason I don't add the `instanceReady` listener to the instance is because the function `setEnabledOnLoad` is called before the instance has been created. This is a result of having the code in two places. GWT has said "ok, create the instance" but Backbone hasn't finished by the time GWT goes to the next line of code and wants to set it enabled/disabled.

Comment: I admit I lack the proper knowledge on Backbone and GWT to take my answer any further :] Hopefully, someone can jump in.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for never updating this with my solution. I needed to decouple the GWT function further from the CKEditor behavior. So, I added a function in GWT 'setEnabled' that is called from the parent object when it wants to update the enabled state of the CKEditor object.

```
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
    toggleCKEditorEnabled(enabled);     
}
```

Then changed the function referenced above 'setEnabledOnLoad' to be 'toggleCKEditorEnabled' which triggers the SET_ENABLED event with the `enabled` value.

Instead of attaching the listener to the specific instance of CKEditor, I added in to the Backbone MessageEntryView class that is the container of the CKEditor instance. In the `initialize` function of the MessageEntryView, I added this line

```
Namespace.on(Namespace.Events.SET_ENABLED, this.setEnabled);
```

This only works because I have one instance of CKEditor loaded on the screen at any given time. This problem and its solution stopped us from being able to add more CKEditor instances to the page at a time, which is something we discussed before moving on and replacing our whole client with Backbone.